# Prestashop swapped images after new theme installed

Tags: image, themes, prestashop

I installed a new theme on a Prestashop site, version 1.6.1.17, and I made regenerate images but it didn't complete. Finally, some images got swapped and others dissapeared.

I don't know how to recover the original images from a backup I made beforehand on my localhost.

Any clues ?

Answer (score 0):

Your images are in `img/` folder. There are subfolders: `p` for products, `c` for categories... These are most important so recover them first.

If regenerating images didn't complete the first time, you can always resume it. Just be sure you set *Erase previous images* option to "No".